# What conditions must we put on a group in order for it to be a vector space over some field?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The axioms specifying the addition operation of a vector space are precisely those defining an abelian group, so of course it needs to be abelian. That's not sufficient though, as per [this quora post.](https://www.quora.com/Can-every-Abelian-group-be-a-vector-space-over-some-field).

Obviously the additive group of any field is a vector space over that field or a subfield when viewed as an extension, but is that all? What groups are possible as the additive group of some vector space over some field?

Comment: I think that you should be able to do at least the case when the field has characteristic $p$ yourself. So you're left with asking which abelian groups can be given the structure of a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.